# GitHub Action run 10 minutes after another action is run (or after a tag is create)

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to trigger GitHub Action a certain amount of time after another action is triggered, or a certain amount of time after a tag is created?

Comment: Can't your first action's step be a sleep?

Comment: As Jarod said, you could use a `sleep` command as the first step of a new job that would trigger after another one finished (for example, using a [workflow run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) trigger)

Comment: I could use a sleep but setting that to 10-15 minutes eats into GitHub Action run time.

Comment: You could call a public repo (as they don't have any run limit) to run a 10 min wait job with a [dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch), and call the private workflow back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    name: wait-job
    steps:
      - name: Sleep for 3 minutes
        run: sleep 180s
        shell: bash
```

Comment: Are there any configurations that won't impact the execution time of the workflow? As you're paying for these three minutes of doing nothing 

Comment: sadly no, Github should *really* consider adding such a thing, but then again, that'd mean not being able to soak us for using their service so they're probably not in a hurry to implement anything.